# Remove events from webform when full?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've looked about but to no avail - hopefully one of you fine people know the answer!

I have a webform with a user-select list for event registration. I would like the events to disappear from the list when they're full. Does anyone know how to make it happen?

I do have the 'show remaining space in events' popup at the top on, so that registrants can see the capacity, but it'd be more user-friendly to have full events removed from the select list.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: No joy I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that this is something which (if you're a coder) could be done via a webform hook, or even better, by modifying the code to do it (should be a simple-ish change to add as an option). This is a good idea for a feature - so why not suggest it at issues.civicrm.org?